# Display Message Using Json in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to display a simple message using Json Where I am going wrong, I could not understand please Help me. My JSON code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = '{ "R000092201": "EIN and Name should be same" }';

    var obj = JSON.parse(text);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.R000092201;
```

My aspx code is

```
<div id="divErrorList" runat="server"  style="line-height: 25px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #E41B17; padding-left: 20px; margin-top: 1%; border: 1px dashed red; background-color: #FBEFEF;">
            <div>
                Rejection Code:
                <asp:Label ID="lblRejectionReason" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div>
                Rejection Reason:
                    <asp:Label ID="demo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my aspx.cs code is

```
if (Convert.ToString(ldr["rejection"]) == "R0000-922-01")
                    {
                        divErrorList.Visible = true;
                        lblRejectionReason.Text = Convert.ToString(ldr["rejection"]);
                        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert();", true);
                       // lblrejectionmsg.Text = Convert.ToString(ldr["rejection_msg"]);
                        contSup.Visible = false;
                        editbtn.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        divErrorList.Visible = true;
                        editbtn.Visible = false;
                        contSup.Visible = true;
                        lblRejectionReason.Text = Convert.ToString(ldr["rejection"]);
                       // lblrejectionmsg.Text = Convert.ToString(ldr["rejection_msg"]);
                    }
```

Comment: just open the developers console in the browser see if there is any error. Your code is fine, but if any JS line above it is giving error, then also it won't work

Comment: I think if the demo Label is inside a contentplaceholder. then its id might be different on client side. If that is the case you can use this property of a server control to make sure it has the same id on client side as well. ClientIDMode="Static"  <asp:Label ID="demo" runat="server" ClientIDMode = "Static"  Text=""></asp:Label>

Comment: It is showing......Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Okay then just add the property and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id of Label might not be the same on the client side. So, most probably js cannot get it. you can use this property on the label **ClientIDMode="Static"** or use a different client side getter like those of jquery. Where you can get a node by name ending in "demo".

```
$("span[id$='demo']")
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just I have changed in script and main thing is help of Khalid Khan I put **ClietIDMode="Static"** in label.  Json Code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = '{ "R000092201": "EIN and Name should be same" }';

    var obj = JSON.parse(text);

    document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.R000092201;
</script>
```

My aspx code is

```
<div>
   Rejection Reason:
   <asp:Label ID="lblrejectionmsg" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Thank you guys for helping me